# Database Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This problem is very simple i think...

I dont have experience with big scalable databases, and im working in a project and im facing this design problem:

I have a table for subscriptors and have a table for the services they could be subscribed to, both tables will grow, the subscriptors can be subscribed to how many services they want, the problem is to estore the relation subscritor -> service i dont know wich would be the proper way, i think it should be one of this options:

- Create a table per service to estore the subscriptor list.
- Create a table for the subscriptors and dinamically add new columns to represent the service.
- Create a table for the subscritors and use a Binary Mask to store the list of services the user is subscribed to.

Wich way would be the best and more practical, and scalable solution? any other options are apreciated. thanks beforehand.

PS: Im using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic many-to-many relationship - in relational databases, the standard way to deal with this is one table for each side of the relationship and one to store the links between them - like so:

```
Subscriber
----------
SubscriberID (PK)
SubscriberName
etc...

Service
-------
ServiceID (PK)
ServiceName
etc...

SubscriberService
-----------------
SubscriberID (PK)
ServiceID    (PK)
```

Comment: @Sevak: - although you didn't mention that this was the standard approach in relational schemas, nor did you supply sample table structures...

Comment: @Aronis Mariano : So what do you want..?? Help for solving the problem or want everything ready (SPOON-FEEDING)... Its not affecting to me...but you would not learn for other projects..

Comment: @Sevak "last one to store which subscriptors have which services"... -> This is very general and subjective... the solution 2 and 3 i detailed satisfy that statement...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one...

```
One table for subscriptors
One table for services and 
last one to store which subscriptors have which services...
```

It would be the best one for your project...